# how to create and run CLI client app interact with user with docker

Tags: python-3.x, input, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need the client CLI python app to interact with the user insert his name, etc...

on main.py there are:
user= input("Please insert user:")

docker-compose.yml:

```
  client:
    container_name: client_container
    image: client:latest
    build: client/
    depends_on:
      - server
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    tty: true # docker run -t
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    network_mode: host

    command: ["python", "./main.py", "-it"]
```

** When I just run this main.py I got the msg to insert user and all works as expected but when add docker not.

Answer (score 0):

I succeed to solve this issue only if I am running the client CLI manually separated (not from docker-compose file)

```
docker build -t client_image .
docker run -it client_image
```